# Is there a tool to analyze which javascript file added a certain portion of html / code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

When analyzing a webpage, I usually open these js files one after another and then read the source code to determine which file added a certain portion of html in the final rendered page. Is there an easy way / tool to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a tool to do such a thing.  Understanding the code yourself or searching for specific key phrases in the HTML you're trying to source (such as a class name or tag name or piece of text) is the typical method.

It could work to grep for the common ways that the DOM is modified (`.innerHTML` property, `.appendChild()`, `.insertBefore`, etc... if it's plain javascript) or similar methods in whatever library is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Partially, you may use Firebug in Mozilla and, viewing the HTML tab, right click some tags and tick "break on child addition/removal". And then reload the page. Javascript execution will pause at any changing of DOM inside the chosen element.

Comment: The same feature is available in Chrome's Developer Tools